# Конструктор меню

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic

Вот скажите, я хочу сделать программу конструктор, вот есть меню (пустое) и вот я хочу, чтобы другие смогли добавлять туда пункты, не имея исходника. Вот, например, есть 2 поля ввода:

1. Название
2. Ссылка

Когда пользователь вводит в первое поле название пункта и ссылку, то когда он нажимает кнопку "Добавить", в меню появляется пункт, который при нажатии переходит на ссылку в элементе `WebBrowser`.

Comment: Как вариант - используйте XML

Comment: А можете сказать где и как его активировать? Или дать название литературы по нему.

Comment: <a href="http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML">Вики</a><br>
В свое время в изучении XML помог видеокурс от "Специалист", как вариант скчать можно <a href="http://letitbit.net/download/3897.3c99db0ab48992356de1f0da2dc7/XML.rar.html">здесь</a> <br>
Вообще нет смысла парится над его изучением если вам нужно только решение данной проблемы, пример кода привести немогу т.к. не VBшник :)<br>
Вообще думаю <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb385097.aspx">тут</a> должно быть достаточно инфы для решения вашей проблемы<br>
PS:XML это язык разметки, т.что писать типа как его включить - бред :)

Comment: Вообщем то даже не суть что именно использовать, суть в том что вам однозначно необходимо хранилище данных, а XML лишь один из вариантов

Answer (score 1):

Вы определитесь, VB у вас или VB.NET. В любом случае для VB-шника задача может показаться непривычно сложной. Вам нужно использовать функции WinAPI (читаем MSDN) для получения хэндла своего окна и хэндла его меню, а далее добавления или удаления пунктов в него. Вот ссылка на доку по добавлению пункта в меню например:
[MSDN AppendMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms647616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

(это про VB)

А в общем ничего особенного, конечно. Где хранить данные - в xml или в ещё где - это непринципиально. Хоть массив названий пунктов держите...

Comment: Я про VB .NET